# Why won't my table row change background color when I hover over it?

Tags: css, hover, html-table, row

I’m trying to get my table row to have a different background color when I hover over it.  So I included this in my stylesheet

```css
table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #F6F8F9
}
```

```html
<table id="subscriptions-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Subscription</th>
      <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even subscription-row header">
      <td class="ig-header-title ellipsis">
        <img src="/assets/s-icon-0d60471f901d65172728d3df0e793b2ee4493a529c1a1dca73409fdae56ad362.png" alt="S icon" />
        <a class="name ellipsis" href="/scenarios/18">My #1 Scenario</a>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <a href="/scenarios/18/download">
          <img src="/assets/zip_icon-c2a0694959db12a0939d264d4283478c1f59a4b118df839d7020aca929a1df61.png" alt="Zip icon" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the Fiddle that demonstrates the problem — https://jsfiddle.net/uwddax6j/ .

Comment: in that fiddle, you set the hover background color to the exact color of the default jsfiddle background.  try changing it to red and it works fine.

Comment: Make a Stack Snippet instead of a JSFiddle and you'll see that it works as is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works if you change the color to something different than the current background color.

Try this:

```
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the issue is not an actual programming issue. This answer is of no real use since there is actually nothing wrong in the question.